# How can I get every distinct size-n combination of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say I have a list:

```
{a, b, c}
```

I would like to, for say $n=2$ get every distinct pair from that list. That is, the expected result should be, for some function `choose`:

```
choose[{a, b, c}, 2]
(* {{a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}} *)
```

My attempt at this was like so:

```
choose[list_, n_] := 
   DeleteDuplicates[Permutations[list, {n}], Union[#1, #2] == #1 &]
```

And it does give the expected result for this example. There are, however, some problems in which I would like some help addressing:

1. `Permutations` creates more combinations that I need, which forces me to use `DeleteDuplicates`. Is there away to directly arrive at all combinations?
2. The `DeleteDuplicates` operation is very costly. Is there a way I could use the structure of the `Permutations` result to my advantage to get rid of the unwanted repeats?
3. My function DOES make an error when there are supposed to be *intended* repeats. For instance, `choose[{b, b, c}, 2]` should give `{{b,b}, {b, c}, {c, b}}` - as every element in the list is considered "distinct" even though the values could be equal - but instead, the duplicate deletion removes the `{c, b}`.

**EDIT**
I have figured out a way to address #3. If I create a symbolic list `tempList` in which every element is unique, then replace that with the list, I am able to preserve "distinct" combinations even though they have the same value:

```
choose[list_, n_] := 
   With[{tempList = Array[Unique[] &, Length@list]}, 
        DeleteDuplicates[
        Permutations[tempList, {n}], 
        Union[#1, #2] == #1 &] /. Thread[tempList -> list]]
```

However, there's still room for improvement as having to use the replacement is not great for larger `list` lengths and values of $n$.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3461/121) and Related: [(2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9537/121).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I expected there to be answers with the same results for different questions, but my approach to what I was looking for was different than what the authors of those linked questions had (that's why I couldn't find those questions before I posted). Users who are need of this function (which they don't know exists, like in this case) are more likely to find it if their interpretation of what they need is similar to mine.

Comment: (cont.) In other words, when they search "choose combinations from a list" or something along those lines, this will come up.

Comment: You will notice that I didn't Close this question, and furthermore I would not Delete it if I (or someone else) had.  Frankly I'm considering closing #3461 in favor of this one as I think it's much more likely to be found.  The second linked question is not a duplicate; I should have instead said Related: (I'll fix that now.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard gotcha, I wasn't trying to be too defensive.

Comment: Are you reading through your **responses** tab backlog? :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just check up on any questions if I see something changes - this site always teaches me something new.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think there is a built-in function for what you need:

```
Subsets[{a, b, c, d}, {2}]
```

Comment: Ah! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Some of the points in the question were never well addressed.

> 1. `Permutations` creates more combinations that I need, which forces me to use `DeleteDuplicates`. Is there away to directly arrive
>      at all combinations?
> 2. The `DeleteDuplicates` operation is very costly. Is there a way I could use the structure of the `Permutations` result to my advantage
>      to get rid of the unwanted repeats?

`Permutations` is "smart" enough not to produce needless duplicates if you ask it for the right thing: it recognizes identical elements as such and does not produce repetitious output.  Therefore your mask may be had with:

```
Permutations[{1, 1, 0}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}
> ```

And applied with `Pick`:

```
Pick[{a, b, c}, #, 1] & /@ Permutations[{1, 1, 0}]
```

> ```
> {{a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}}
> ```

This method inherently addresses point #3 as well.