# Permuting indices to form fully symmetric tensor with repeated indices

Tags: function-construction

I have written a function (version 8) that takes as an input a list of indices such as `{i,j,k}` and outputs a fully symmetric tensor function containing $p_i$ and $g_{ij}$ ($g_{ij}$ is itself understood to be symmetric under $i\leftrightarrow j$).

```
myFunc[tensorList_?ListQ] := Module[{rank = Length[tensorList], perms, i, j, k, r},
  perms = Select[Permutations[tensorList, {rank}], Signature[#] == 1 &];

  Return[Sum[If[rank <= 1, 1, 2^(1 - r)/(r! (rank - 2 r)!)]*
    Factor[Sum[
      Product[Subscript[p, perms[[i]][[j]]],
        {j, 1, rank - 2 r}] 
      Product[Subscript[g, Times @@ perms[[i]][[2 k - 1 ;; 2 k]]],
        {k, rank/2 - r + 1, rank/2}], {i, 1, Max[1, rank!/2]}]] 
    f[2 r, rank], {r, 0, rank/2}]]
]
```

Example of usage:

`myFunc[{i}]` returns $f[0, 1]p_i$

`myFunc[{i,j}]` returns $f[2, 2]g_{ij}+f[0,2]p_i p_j$.

etc.

**Problem:** My function only works when all elements of input list have unique names like `{i,j,k}`.  I don't know how to modify it so that it can accept lists like `{i,j,j}`.

for example, I'd like `myFunc[{i,i}]` to return $f[2,2]\,g_{i^2}+f[0,2]p_i p_i$.

*and yes, I know that I'm multiplying indices of g, which I'd like to keep.*

Any hints please?  (and any pointers on ethics of function construction would be nice!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address your question on a high level only (how do I make my function to interpret the input `{i, j, j}` to contain distinct elements, like `{i, j, k}`), I recommend an approach similar to one that I made in [one of my own questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17242/how-can-i-get-every-distinct-size-n-combination-of-a-list):

```
myOtherFunc[list_] := 
  With[{tempList = Array[Unique[] &, Length@list]}, 
     myFunc[tempList] /. Thread[tempList -> list]]
```

This gives you the results you're looking for because it replaces your input symbols with temporary unique symbols (which are treated as such in your function), and then replaces them with the desired ones afterwards.

Regarding your function, since you asked for some pointers:

A bit of `Part` cleanup helps. Instead of `[[i]][[j]]` consider `[[i, j]]`.

For symbols like `perms`, which you only define once then keep unchanged, it's better to use the faster `With` rather than `Module`. In fact, `LetL` makes more sense than nested `With`s (the code for `LetL` is somewhere on this site, I swear).

Get rid of the `Return`.

Instead of using your `If` construct (whose static condition is needlessly evaluated for every `Sum` iteration), create a variable `e` (again using the ever so convenient `LetL`).

**EDIT:** scoping `i, j, k, r` is unnecessary if you use the `myOtherFunc` construct b/c it already replaces your variables with unique ones, effectively re-creating the `Module`.

Here's the improved `myFunc`:

```
myFunc[tensorList_?ListQ] := 
  LetL[{
    rank = Length[tensorList], 
    perms = Select[Permutations[tensorList, {rank}], Signature[#] == 1 &],
    e = If[rank <= 1, 1, 2^(1 - r)/(r! (rank - 2 r)!)]},
    Sum[
      e *
      Factor[Sum[
        Product[Subscript[p, perms[[i, j]]], {j, 1, rank - 2 r}] *
        Product[Subscript[g, Times @@ perms[[i, 2 k - 1 ;; 2 k]]], {k, rank/2 - r + 1, rank/2}],
        {i, 1, Max[1, rank!/2]}]] *
      f[2 r, rank],
    {r, 0, rank/2}]
  ]
```

**EDIT 2**:
Just something that came to me as I was viewing `myOtherFunc`:

```
#[] & /@ ConstantArray[Unique, len]
```

Is functionally equivalent to

```
Array[Unique[] &, len]
```

But the former is 10x faster b/c it takes advantage of the controlled evaluation and is more memory efficient during computation.

Comment: This is excellent!  Thanks!

Comment: @QuantumDot I added some stuff regarding your function. [LetL is here.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/how-to-avoid-nested-with)

Comment: Wonderful edit with very helpful comments!  The reason I localized {i,j,k,r} is because otherwise I couldn't use i,j,... as elements of the input list.  It seems to lead to conflicting variables.

Comment: @QuantumDot Ah! I see - I was only considering the case that an external value for `i` would influence the iteration, not the other way around. Even in this case, it's better to localize differently (I'll put up an edit)