# Generating all "from n choose k" configurations of a simple list

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

Suppose that I have a 1-D list called `myList`.  Here's an example:

```
myList = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
```

I want to write (or find built-in) a function called `getConfigurations` that will return all possible "n choose k" lists.  Before I explain what I mean by an "n choose k" list, let me just write down the result I would like to obtain from `getConfigurations` for the list `myList` given above:

```
getConfigurations[myList]
```

> ```
> {
>
>   (* configurations when ONE element is chosen: k=1 *)
>  {{"A"}, {"B"}, {"C"}, {"D"}}, 
>
>   (* configurations when TWO elements are chosen: k=2 *)
>  {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "C"}, {"A", "D"}, {"B", "C"}, {"B", "D"}, {"C", "D"}},
>
>   (* configurations when THREE elements are chosen: k=3 *)
>  {{"A", "B", "C"}, {"A", "B", "D"}, {"A", "C", "D"}, {"B", "C", "D"}},
>
>   (* configurations when FOUR elements are chosen: k=4 *)
>  {{"A", "B", "C", "D"}} 
>
>  }
> ```

I am not sure what (if anything) this is called in combinatorics, but it reminds me of the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient):

$${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}$$

which I remember being called the "n choose k" binomial coefficient.

In the example `myList` given above, $n = 4$ because `Length[myList]` is 4.  For each value of k ($k = 1, 2, 3, 4$), I want to generate all possible configurations.  In my case, order does ***not*** matter, so for example, `{"B", "A"}` is indistinguishable from `{"A", "B"}`.

I think that the formula for $n \choose k$ gives the *number* of configurations.  It turns out that

$${4 \choose 1} = 4$$
$${4 \choose 2} = 6$$
$${4 \choose 3} = 4$$
$${4 \choose 4} = 1$$

which can be seen from `Table[Binomial[4, k], {k, 1, 4}]`.

***However,*** I don't just want the *number* of possible configurations for each k; instead, I want to actually generate the configurations themselves.  ***Is there a simple and elegant -- or perhaps even built-in -- way to do this?***

Comment: `Subsets[myList, {k}]`

Comment: See also: [(17242)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17242) and [(9537)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9537)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Subsets` does what you want:

```
myList = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};

Column[Table[{k, Subsets[myList, {k}]}, {k, 1, 4}]]

(*
{1,{{A},{B},{C},{D}}}
{2,{{A,B},{A,C},{A,D},{B,C},{B,D},{C,D}}}
{3,{{A,B,C},{A,B,D},{A,C,D},{B,C,D}}}
{4,{{A,B,C,D}}}
*)
```