# How to generate all possible orderless partitions of a list according to another list?

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, partitions

This question is hard to describe in plain text. So I will post an example and a working code (brute force) to illustrate.

For example I have a list: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` and a partition list `{2, 2, 1}`. I will first choose 2 elements (there are 10 ways to do so), and then choose another 2 elements from the rest of the list (of length 3 and there are 3 ways to do so). The output is

```
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4}}, {{1, 2}, {4, 
   5}, {3}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4}}, {{1, 
   3}, {4, 5}, {2}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 
   5}, {3}}, {{1, 4}, {3, 5}, {2}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {4}}, {{1, 
   5}, {2, 4}, {3}}, {{1, 5}, {3, 4}, {2}}, {{2, 3}, {1, 
   4}, {5}}, {{2, 3}, {1, 5}, {4}}, {{2, 3}, {4, 5}, {1}}, {{2, 
   4}, {1, 3}, {5}}, {{2, 4}, {1, 5}, {3}}, {{2, 4}, {3, 
   5}, {1}}, {{2, 5}, {1, 3}, {4}}, {{2, 5}, {1, 4}, {3}}, {{2, 
   5}, {3, 4}, {1}}, {{3, 4}, {1, 2}, {5}}, {{3, 4}, {1, 
   5}, {2}}, {{3, 4}, {2, 5}, {1}}, {{3, 5}, {1, 2}, {4}}, {{3, 
   5}, {1, 4}, {2}}, {{3, 5}, {2, 4}, {1}}, {{4, 5}, {1, 
   2}, {3}}, {{4, 5}, {1, 3}, {2}}, {{4, 5}, {2, 3}, {1}}}
```

The current working code is very memory-inefficient because it generates unnecessary lists first and deletes them later. Here it is:

```
f[list_, partition_] := 
 DeleteDuplicates[
  Sort /@ Internal`PartitionRagged[#, partition] & /@ 
   Permutations[list]]
```

I am also working on using `Subsets` to generate directly, but I have got lost in `Fold`ing with brackets, and the code is very long. Any elegant or efficient solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: [(3044)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3044/121), [(8528)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8528/121), [(19672)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19672/121).  Somewhat less related: [(5036)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5036/121)

Comment: Is it intentional that the desired result contains both `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}}` and `{{3, 4}, {1, 2}, {5}}`?  They differ only in order, albeit at a higher level than the raw elements.

Comment: @WReach yes, the groups are distinct.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A solution using [`Repeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html), [`ReplaceList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceList.html), and the [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) attribute.

```
part[a_List, p_List] := 
  Module[{f, sym},
    Attributes[f] = Orderless;
    sym = Unique["x", Temporary] & /@ p;
    ReplaceList[
      f @@ a, 
      f @@ MapThread[Pattern[#, Repeated[_, {#2}]] &, {sym, p}] -> List /@ sym
    ]
  ]

part[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 2, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}}, . . ., {{4, 5}, {2, 3}, {1}}}
> ```

This proves to be an order of magnitude faster than BoLe's code:

```
SeedRandom[1]
p = RandomInteger[{1, 3}, 6];
a = Range @ Tr @ p;

Flatten[split[a, p]] /. sol -> List  // Length // RepeatedTiming

part[a, p]                           // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.7517, 45360}
>
> {0.0766, 45360}
> ```

---

#### Relation to `Permutations`

*Note: I completely overlooked Simon Woods's answer before starting on this section.  Nevertheless after reading and digesting his answer I believe I have something unique to offer.*

I was reminded of a different approach to this problem using [`Permutations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations.html) thanks to an apparently coincidental vote on an old answer of mine:

- [How can I get every distinct size-n combination of a list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17242/how-can-i-get-every-distinct-size-n-combination-of-a-list/30016#30016)

Consider that there is a one-to-one mapping between your target list and this:

```
Permutations[{1, 1, 2, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 3, 2}, . . ., {3, 2, 1, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 2, 1, 1}}
> ```

`Permutations` by itself is very efficient.  It is nearly two orders of magnitude better than `part` defined above, and its output takes a fraction of the memory:

```
maskFn = Permutations @* Flatten @* MapIndexed[Table[#2, {#}] &];

a = Range @ 12;
p = {2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1};

part[a, p] // ByteCount // RepeatedTiming
maskFn[p]  // ByteCount // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {6.49, 2075673680}
>
> {0.0984, 319334552}
> ```

If you can write whatever operations follow this in terms of the permutation masks rather than the partitions there is clearly the potential for a major optimization.

*Now, after reading Simon's answer and being inspired by it, I offer the following solution.*

We can use `Ordering` as Simon did to convert the permutations, and then split the result using a slight modification of my `dynP` from:

- [Partitioning with varying partition size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/partitioning-with-varying-partition-size/7512#7512)

This provides my second proposal:

```
maskFn = Permutations @* Flatten @* MapIndexed[Table[#2, {#}] &];

dynP2[m_, p_] := 
 MapThread[
   m[[All, # ;; #2]] &,
   {{0} ~Join~ Most@# + 1, #} & @ Accumulate @ p
 ]\[Transpose]

part2[a_List, p_List] := dynP2[a[[ Ordering @ # ]] & /@ maskFn[p], p]
```

Comparing (in v10.1) the performance of both of my functions to Simon's `parts`:

```
a = Alphabet[] ~Take~ 11;
p = {2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2};

RepeatedTiming @ Length @ #[a, p] & /@ {part, part2, parts}
```

> ```
> {{1.452, 831600}, {2.052, 831600}, {2.30, 831600}}
> ```

And again but with a packable `a` list:

```
a = Range @ 11;
p = {2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2};

RepeatedTiming @ Length @ #[a, p] & /@ {part, part2, parts}
```

> ```
> {{1.45, 831600}, {1.59, 831600}, {1.43, 831600}}
> ```

It seems to me that `part` is still the best general function, but Simon's code is slightly faster in the case of a packed/packable input list.

Answer (score 15):

`Permutations` treats repeated elements as identical, so you can get a flattened version of the desired result with something like

```
Ordering /@ Permutations[{1, 1, 2, 2, 3}]

(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 3} ... {4, 5, 2, 3, 1} *)
```

A simple solution based on this idea:

```
parts[list_, p_] := Module[{q},
  q = Flatten@MapThread[ConstantArray, {Range@Length@p, p}];
  Internal`PartitionRagged[list[[Ordering[#]]], p] & /@ Permutations[q]]
```

Unforunately `` Internal`PartitionRagged `` is rather slow; it is faster (though less elegant) to create a function which does the reshaping:

```
parts[list_, p_] := Module[{q, f, slot},
  q = Flatten@MapThread[ConstantArray, {Range@Length@p, p}];
  f = Function @@ {Internal`PartitionRagged[Array[slot, Length@list], p]} /. slot -> Slot;
  f @@@ (list[[Ordering[#]]] & /@ Permutations[q])]
```

This is comparable to Mr Wizard's in terms of speed.

Comment: Nuts!  Why do I always see these answers *after* I update my posts?

Answer (score 12):

It's far from pretty, using pattern matching (`OrderlessPatternSequence`):

```
ReplaceList[#1,
  Module[{names = Unique[] & /@ #1, partitions},
    partitions = Internal`PartitionRagged[names, #2]; 
    Activate[{OrderlessPatternSequence @@ (Pattern[#, _] & /@ names)} /; 
       Evaluate[And @@ (Inactive@OrderedQ /@ partitions)] :> 
      Evaluate@partitions]]] &[Range@5, {2, 2, 1}]
```

The pattern we construct for the case of these arguments is:

```
{OrderlessPatternSequence[$3_, $4_, $5_, $6_, $7_]} /; 
 OrderedQ[{$3, $4}] && OrderedQ[{$5, $6}] && OrderedQ[{$7}] :> 
 {{$3, $4}, {$5, $6}, {$7}}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
split1[s_List, p_List] :=
 (Fold[#1 /. temp[b___List] :> Map[
         temp[b, #] &, Subsets[Complement[s, b], {#2}]] &,
     temp[], p] // Flatten) /. temp -> List
```

---

**Edit:** I cleaned the code slightly, as the temporary head is unnecessary.

```
split2[s_List, p_List] :=
 Fold[#1 /. {x : {__Integer} ..} :> Sequence @@ Map[
       {x, #} &, Subsets[Complement[s, x], {#2}]] &,
  List /@ Subsets[s, {First@p}], Rest@p]
```

The code is always an order of magnitude slower than the fastest, yet it seems to share the computational complexity with them.

```
problem[n_] := {Range@Total@#, #} &@RandomInteger[{1, 3}, n]

timing[n_, methods__] := Module[{pr},
  pr = problem[n];
  Table[{n, RepeatedTiming[m @@ pr;][[1]]}, {m, {methods}}]]

data = Table[timing[n, split1, split2, parts], {n, 6}];

ListLogPlot[Transpose[data],
 Joined -> True,
 Mesh -> All,
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLegends -> {"BoLe 1", "BoLe 2", "Simon Woods"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot for not using `Complement[]`, which would have made a generic version of my answer so much simpler.

Answer (score 7):

```
g[l_, {n1_, n2_}] := (sb = Subsets[l, {n1}];
  Flatten[
   Table[{i1 = sb[[i]], i2 = Subsets[Complement[l, i1], {n2}][[j]], 
     Complement[l, {i1, i2}]}, {j, Length[l] - n1 - 1}, {i, 
     Length[sb]}], 1])
AbsoluteTiming[g[l, {2, 2}]]
```

> 0.000256

```
AbsoluteTiming[f[l, {2, 2, 1}]]
```

> 0.002062

Comment: thanks, but actually the partition list is not limited to length 2

Comment: @happyfish This code works for any partition of 3, for example try `AbsoluteTiming[g[Range[9], {4, 3}]]` for `{4,3,2}`

Comment: yes, I meant, partitions like {2, 3, 3, 3}

Comment: @happyfish I see, well kirma 's already works for any kind, so rather than me expanding mine, you can accept his ;)

Answer (score 3):

FoldPairList, introduced in version 10.2 (but still [[EXPERIMENTAL]]), combined with the use of Ordering and Permutations, does what you want:

```
FoldPairList[TakeDrop, #, {2, 2, 1}] & /@ (Ordering /@ Permutations[{1, 1, 2, 2, 3}])
```