# Totally orderless partition

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, replacement, partitions

This is a slight variation of: [How to generate all possible orderless partitions of a list according to another list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123835/how-to-generate-all-possible-orderless-partitions-of-a-list-according-to-another/123846#123846)

Consider each set following a partition a "box" and each element a "ball".

**What are all the possible partitions where the balls are distinct but boxes are identical(i.e. no ordering among the boxes) and there is no ordering of the balls in a box?**

(Note that @Mr. Wizard's answer covered the case where the balls inside any given  box was orderless. I am going a step further and demanding the boxes to be treated identical.)

**My attempt:**

I assume that the partition sizes are non-decreasing(eg {1,2,2) for the set{1,2,3,4,5}) so that I can use `OrderedQ` to filter the identical(canonical) configurations.

```
part[a_List, p_List] := Module[{f, sym}, Attributes[f] = Orderless;
  sym = Unique["x", Temporary] & /@ p;
  ReplaceList[f @@ a, 
   With[{patt = 
       MapThread[Pattern[#1, Repeated[_, {#2}]] &, {sym, p}]}, (f @@ 
        patt) /; OrderedQ[patt] == 0] -> List /@ sym]]
```

or

```
part[a_List, p_List] := Module[{f, sym}, Attributes[f] = Orderless;
  sym = Unique["x", Temporary] & /@ p;
  ReplaceList[f @@ a, , 
   f @@ (patt : 
        MapThread[
         Pattern[#1, Repeated[_, {#2}]] &, {sym, p}]) /; (OrderedQ[
        patt] == 0) :> List /@ sym]]
```

Now, if one tries to evaluate:

```
part[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 2}]
```

duplicates in :

```
{{{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{1}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}, {{1}, {2, 5}, {3, 
   4}}, {{1}, {3, 4}, {2, 5}}, {{1}, {3, 5}, {2, 4}}, {{1}, {4, 
   5}, {2, 3}}, {{2}, {1, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{2}, {1, 4}, {3, 
   5}}, {{2}, {1, 5}, {3, 4}}, {{2}, {3, 4}, {1, 5}}, {{2}, {3, 
   5}, {1, 4}}, {{2}, {4, 5}, {1, 3}}, {{3}, {1, 2}, {4, 
   5}}, {{3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}}, {{3}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}}, {{3}, {2, 
   4}, {1, 5}}, {{3}, {2, 5}, {1, 4}}, {{3}, {4, 5}, {1, 
   2}}, {{4}, {1, 2}, {3, 5}}, {{4}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}}, {{4}, {1, 
   5}, {2, 3}}, {{4}, {2, 3}, {1, 5}}, {{4}, {2, 5}, {1, 
   3}}, {{4}, {3, 5}, {1, 2}}, {{5}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5}, {1, 
   3}, {2, 4}}, {{5}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}}, {{5}, {2, 3}, {1, 
   4}}, {{5}, {2, 4}, {1, 3}}, {{5}, {3, 4}, {1, 2}}}
```

like:
`{{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}` and  `{{1}, {4, 5}, {2, 3}}` should not appear anymore.

But, none of them work. Help will be appreciated.

**Edit 1**:

This is another attempt I made, which returns the same answer. `OrderedQ` doesn't seem to work:

```
part[a_List, p_List] := Module[{f, sym}, Attributes[f] = Orderless;
  sym = Unique["x", Temporary] & /@ p;
  ReplaceList[f @@ a, 
   With[{patt = 
      MapThread[Pattern[#1, Repeated[_, {#2}]] &, {sym, p}]}, 
    Rule[Condition[f @@ patt, OrderedQ[List /@ sym] == True], 
     List /@ sym]]]]
```

Comment: Is `DeleteDuplicatesBy[yourResult, Sort]` what you are looking for?

Comment: @MarcoB No. I don't want to use `DeleteDuplicatesBy` as it will probably be inefficient for a large list. I want to instead use `OrderedQ`  or the likes as I have mentioned in my post.

Comment: @MarcoB Can you just find the bug in my existing code? This is just a slight variation of Mr. Wizard's referenced answer from a long time back.

Answer (score 3):

Say the output of your part function is called "list". Then

```
Union[Sort /@ list]
```

removes the duplicates.

Comment: `DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, Sort]` would also achieve your same result; it avoids changing the sorting of the overall list, in case that is not desirable.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
OrderlessPartition[set_List, part_List] := 
 Module[{f, part2, list}, Attributes[f] = Orderless;
  part2 = Sort@part;
  list = Unique["x", Temporary] & /@ part2; 
  ReplaceList[f @@ set, 
   With[{list1 = list, list2 = List /@ list}, 
    f @@ (MapThread[
         Pattern[#1, Repeated[_, {#2}]] &, {list1, part2}]) /; 
      OrderedQ[list2] -> List /@ list1]]]
```

e.g.

```
OrderlessPartition[Range[6], {1, 2, 3}]
```

> {{{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{1}, {2, 4}, {3, 5, 6}}, {{1}, {2, 5}, {3,
>       4, 6}}, {{1}, {2, 6}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{1}, {3, 4}, {2, 5, 
>      6}}, {{1}, {3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}}, {{1}, {3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}}, {{1}, {4, 
>      5}, {2, 3, 6}}, {{1}, {4, 6}, {2, 3, 5}}, {{1}, {5, 6}, {2, 3, 
>      4}}, {{2}, {1, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{2}, {1, 4}, {3, 5, 6}}, {{2}, {1, 
>      5}, {3, 4, 6}}, {{2}, {1, 6}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{2}, {3, 4}, {1, 5, 
>      6}}, {{2}, {3, 5}, {1, 4, 6}}, {{2}, {3, 6}, {1, 4, 5}}, {{2}, {4, 
>      5}, {1, 3, 6}}, {{2}, {4, 6}, {1, 3, 5}}, {{2}, {5, 6}, {1, 3, 
>      4}}, {{3}, {1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5, 6}}, {{3}, {1, 
>      5}, {2, 4, 6}}, {{3}, {1, 6}, {2, 4, 5}}, {{3}, {2, 4}, {1, 5, 
>      6}}, {{3}, {2, 5}, {1, 4, 6}}, {{3}, {2, 6}, {1, 4, 5}}, {{3}, {4, 
>      5}, {1, 2, 6}}, {{3}, {4, 6}, {1, 2, 5}}, {{3}, {5, 6}, {1, 2, 
>      4}}, {{4}, {1, 2}, {3, 5, 6}}, {{4}, {1, 3}, {2, 5, 6}}, {{4}, {1, 
>      5}, {2, 3, 6}}, {{4}, {1, 6}, {2, 3, 5}}, {{4}, {2, 3}, {1, 5, 
>      6}}, {{4}, {2, 5}, {1, 3, 6}}, {{4}, {2, 6}, {1, 3, 5}}, {{4}, {3, 
>      5}, {1, 2, 6}}, {{4}, {3, 6}, {1, 2, 5}}, {{4}, {5, 6}, {1, 2, 
>      3}}, {{5}, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 6}}, {{5}, {1, 3}, {2, 4, 6}}, {{5}, {1, 
>      4}, {2, 3, 6}}, {{5}, {1, 6}, {2, 3, 4}}, {{5}, {2, 3}, {1, 4, 
>      6}}, {{5}, {2, 4}, {1, 3, 6}}, {{5}, {2, 6}, {1, 3, 4}}, {{5}, {3, 
>      4}, {1, 2, 6}}, {{5}, {3, 6}, {1, 2, 4}}, {{5}, {4, 6}, {1, 2, 
>      3}}, {{6}, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{6}, {1, 3}, {2, 4, 5}}, {{6}, {1, 
>      4}, {2, 3, 5}}, {{6}, {1, 5}, {2, 3, 4}}, {{6}, {2, 3}, {1, 4, 
>      5}}, {{6}, {2, 4}, {1, 3, 5}}, {{6}, {2, 5}, {1, 3, 4}}, {{6}, {3, 
>      4}, {1, 2, 5}}, {{6}, {3, 5}, {1, 2, 4}}, {{6}, {4, 5}, {1, 2, 3}}}