# How to get a combination of lists from a large list?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a list with ten elements, for example:

```
{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10}
```

I want to have all the combinations of the 3 elements-list like below:

```
{{x1,x2,x3},{x1,x2,x4},{x1,x2,x5},.....,{x2,x3,x4},{x2,x3,x5},......}
```

I cannot find a function to do this.

Comment: `Subsets[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10}, {3}]`?

Comment: Wait, do you want to allow for permutations, I mean, do you want to have also the combinations `{x1,x2,x3}` and `{x2,x1,x3}`? If so, then this might help `Select[Permutations[Array[x, 10], 3], Length[#] == 3 &]`

Comment: [17242](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17242/5478)

Comment: @Mauricio Lobos.No, I don't want permutations. just{x1,x2,x3}and other combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5};

Subsets[lst, {3}]
```

> {{x1, x2, x3}, {x1, x2, x4}, {x1, x2, x5}, {x1, x3, x4}, {x1, x3, 
>     x5}, {x1, x4, x5}, {x2, x3, x4}, {x2, x3, x5}, {x2, x4, x5}, {x3, 
>     x4, x5}}

Or, if the order matters,

```
Permutations[lst, {3}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]