# Equivalent Nested Loop Structure (combinations_with_replacement)

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, combinatorics, coding-style, permutation

Consider the following examples:

```
Flatten @ Table[ f[a, b, c], {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}, {c, 1, 3}] ==
f @@@ Tuples[ Range[3], 3]

Flatten @ Table[ If[ a != b != c, f[a, b, c], Unevaluated[]], 
                 {a, 1, 3}, {b,  1, 3}, {c, 1, 3}] == 
f @@@ Permutations[ Range[3], {3}]

Flatten @ Table[ f[a, b, c], {a, 1, 5}, {b, a + 1, 5}, {c, b + 1, 5}] == 
f @@@ Subsets[ Range[5], {3}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
True
True
```

Is there a similar built-in function performing this:

```
Flatten @ Table[ f[a, b, c], {a, 1, 5}, {b, a, 5}, {c, b, 5}]
```

in a simpler way?

There is a similar function in python, [combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement).

Comment: Thought I'd give `IntegerPartitions` a try, it backfired :) `f @@@ Sort@
  Flatten[IntegerPartitions[#, {3}, Range[5, 1, -1]] & /@ 
    Range[3, 15], 1]`

Comment: Related link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3461/how-do-i-generate-the-upper-triangular-indices-from-a-list/34879, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319222/combinations-with-repetition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a two more ways, neither of them built-in.
`f @@ (# - {0,1,2})& /@ Subsets[Range@7,{3}]`
`f @@@ Transpose[Transpose@Subsets[Range@7,{3}] - {0,1,2}]`

EDIT - The question is related to a long and somewhat tangled MathGroup thread [generating submultisets with repeated elements](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Oct/msg00037.html). "sms" below stands for for "submultisets".

```
sms[n_, k_, f_:List] := With[{i = Table[Unique[],{k}]}, Flatten[Table[f@@i,
   Evaluate[Sequence@@Transpose@{i,Prepend[Most@i,1],Table[n,{k}]}]],k-1]]

sms[5, 3]
sms[5, 3, f]
```

> {{1,1,1}, {1,1,2}, {1,1,3}, {1,1,4}, {1,1,5}, {1,2,2}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {1,2,5},
>   {1,3,3}, {1,3,4}, {1,3,5}, {1,4,4}, {1,4,5}, {1,5,5}, {2,2,2}, {2,2,3}, {2,2,4},
>   {2,2,5}, {2,3,3}, {2,3,4}, {2,3,5}, {2,4,4}, {2,4,5}, {2,5,5}, {3,3,3}, {3,3,4},
>   {3,3,5}, {3,4,4}, {3,4,5}, {3,5,5}, {4,4,4}, {4,4,5}, {4,5,5}, {5,5,5}}
>
> {f[1,1,1], f[1,1,2], f[1,1,3], f[1,1,4], f[1,1,5], f[1,2,2], f[1,2,3], f[1,2,4], f[1,2,5],
>   f[1,3,3], f[1,3,4], f[1,3,5], f[1,4,4], f[1,4,5], f[1,5,5], f[2,2,2], f[2,2,3], f[2,2,4],
>   f[2,2,5], f[2,3,3], f[2,3,4], f[2,3,5], f[2,4,4], f[2,4,5], f[2,5,5], f[3,3,3], f[3,3,4],
>   f[3,3,5], f[3,4,4], f[3,4,5], f[3,5,5], f[4,4,4], f[4,4,5], f[4,5,5], f[5,5,5]}

```
sms[data_List, k_, f_:List] := With[{i = Table[Unique[],{k}]}, Flatten[Table[f@@data[[i]],
   Evaluate[Sequence@@Transpose@{i,Prepend[Most@i,1],Table[Length@data,{k}]}]],k-1]]

data = {a,b,c,d,e};
sms[data, 3]
sms[data, 3, f]
```

> {{a,a,a}, {a,a,b}, {a,a,c}, {a,a,d}, {a,a,e}, {a,b,b}, {a,b,c}, {a,b,d}, {a,b,e},
>   {a,c,c}, {a,c,d}, {a,c,e}, {a,d,d}, {a,d,e}, {a,e,e}, {b,b,b}, {b,b,c}, {b,b,d},
>   {b,b,e}, {b,c,c}, {b,c,d}, {b,c,e}, {b,d,d}, {b,d,e}, {b,e,e}, {c,c,c}, {c,c,d},
>   {c,c,e}, {c,d,d}, {c,d,e}, {c,e,e}, {d,d,d}, {d,d,e}, {d,e,e}, {e,e,e}}
>
> {f[a,a,a], f[a,a,b], f[a,a,c], f[a,a,d], f[a,a,e], f[a,b,b], f[a,b,c], f[a,b,d], f[a,b,e],
>   f[a,c,c], f[a,c,d], f[a,c,e], f[a,d,d], f[a,d,e], f[a,e,e], f[b,b,b], f[b,b,c], f[b,b,d],
>   f[b,b,e], f[b,c,c], f[b,c,d], f[b,c,e], f[b,d,d], f[b,d,e], f[b,e,e], f[c,c,c], f[c,c,d],
>   f[c,c,e], f[c,d,d], f[c,d,e], f[c,e,e], f[d,d,d], f[d,d,e], f[d,e,e], f[e,e,e]}

Answer (score 7):

**Edit**

I like this one:

```
l = Flatten[{#, #, #} & /@ Range@5]
f @@@ Union@Subsets[l, 3]
```

**Older**

Two alternatives:

```
 f @@@ Select[Tuples[Range@5, 3], Sort@# == # &]
```

or

```
f @@@ Union[Sort /@ Tuples[Range@5, 3]]
```

None of them is a ready-to-use-builtin, though.

**Edit**

Also:

```
Union@Normal@Flatten@SparseArray[{i_, j_, k_} :> f[i, j, k] /; i <= j <= k, {5, 5, 5}, f[1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: `OrderedQ` should be a bit faster than `Sort@# == #&` for larger input

Comment: Why not `Subsets` instead of `KSubsets`?  E.g. `l = Flatten[{#, #, #} & /@ Range@5]f @@@ Union@Subsets[l, {3}]`

Comment: @DavidCarraher Indeed! Edited

Answer (score 7):

This should be the most general and and simple enough:

```
f[x, y, z] /. Solve[ 1 <= x <= y <= z <= 5, {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

Here we have used  `ReplaceAll` (`/.`)  and `Solve` only.

More efficient ways make use of `Tuples` which can work with any head therefore these two approaches using `OrderedQ` (noticed by `ssch` in the comments) should be more efficient than applying `f` to a long list of `3`-tuples:

```
Cases[ Tuples[ f @@ Range @ 5, 3], _?OrderedQ]
```

or

```
DeleteCases[ Tuples[ f @@ Range @ 5, 3], _?(! OrderedQ @ # &)]
```

and they are all equal, e.g.:

```
Cases[ Tuples[ f @@ Range @ 5, 3], _?OrderedQ] == 
Flatten[ Table[ f[a, b, c], {a, 1, 5}, {b, a, 5}, {c, b, 5}], 2]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Note that `Tuples` is very fast and (most likely) it couldn't be overcome by anything else. Thus I guess these two methods should be the most efficient.

We can get rid of `Apply` from `Tuples` using simply e.g.:

```
Cases[ Tuples[ f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3], _?OrderedQ]
```

in case `f` has been defined, we would use something like this:

```
Cases[ Tuples[ ff[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3], _?OrderedQ] /. ff -> f
```

where `ff` is undefined.

otherwise `f` should be applied at the first level of selected tuples:

```
f @@@ Cases[ Tuples[ Range @ 5, 3], _?OrderedQ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an elegant built-in like in your example. I have been trying to find a way to construct the list *without* creating unnecessary elements but I can't really do much better than this:

```
Flatten@Table[f[a, b, c], {a, 1, 5}, {b, a, 5}, {c, b, 5}] === 
f @@@ Sort@Flatten[MapIndexed[Outer[List, Range[#1], #2, Range[5, #2, -1]] &, 
     Range[5]], 4]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

This should be quicker -especially if you go beyond `Range[5]`- but it's still slower than `Table` because of `Sort`. If you can skip the ordering (by making the function `Orderless` or by not caring) you get something that scales with `Table`.