# List of tuples without duplicates & repeated values

Tags: combinatorics, sorting, tuples

Given some number `n`and set of values `vals`, I want to obtain all the tuples/permutations of size `n` for the values in `vals`, but without any repeated tuples. So e.g. `n=2` and `vals={3,6}` should give

```
 n = 2, vals = {0,1}   --> { {0,0}, {0,1}, {1,1} }
 n = 2, vals = {0,1,2} --> { {0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2}, {1,1}, {1,2}, {2,2} }
 n = 3, vals = {0,1}   --> { {0,0,0}, {0,0,1}, {0,1,1}, {1,1,1} }
 n = 3, vals = {0,1,2} --> { {0,0,0}, {0,0,1}, {0,0,2}, {0,1,1}, {0,1,2}, {0,2,2}, {1,1,1}, {1,1,2}, {1,2,2}, {2,2,2} }
```

I've tried the following commands:

```
 n    = 2;
 vals = {0, 1};
 Tuples[vals, {n}]        (* gives { {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1} } *)
 Permutations[vals, {n}]  (* gives { {0, 1}, {1, 0} } *)
 Subsets[vals, {n}]       (* gives { {0, 1} } *)
```

`Permutations` and `Subsets` are incomplete. `Tuples` contains all the right combinations, but also contains duplicates like `{0, 1}` and `{1, 0}`. Since I do not care about order, I'd like to remove those.

How do I achieve the behavior of `Tuples`, but without duplicates?

Comment: Releated link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35560/equivalent-nested-loop-structure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
n = 2;
vals = {0, 1};
Tuples[vals, {n}] // DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, Sort] &
```

As the comment said

```
Tuples[vals, {n}] // DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]
```

Also works, more clear.

Some explanations:

The key is: you "sort" the list to see whether they are duplicate.

So I use [`Sort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html) to be [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html)'s condition.

Comment: Perfect. Just curious, how does this syntax work?

Comment: @Phil-ZXX I add some explanations.

Comment: @Phil-ZXX if you mean: *this syntax*, then `a//f[#,b]&` == `f[a,b]` , but sometimes a is too long to put in a `[]` .So I use this way to put it out.

Comment: Note that `DeleteDuplicatesBy` has an operator form, so `… // DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]` will also work

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer will quickly blow up with arguments of more than trivial sizes.

For example, with `vals = {10, 20, 5, a, b, c}` and `n=10`, it takes nearly two minutes to finish on my laptop, generating only 3003 results.

Better to generate the results directly, as a simple nested iteration:

```
f2[vals_, n_] := 
 With[{i = {#2, #1, Length@vals} & @@@ 
     Partition[Prepend[Array[i, n], 1], 2, 1]}, 
  Partition[vals[[Flatten[Table @@ {i[[All, 1]], Sequence @@ i}]]], n]];
```

This takes a few hundredths of a second to generate the same results from the aforementioned example.

It will also handle cases where the current answer will simply crash out with a "insufficient memory available" error (say 20 values and length 10).