# How to get elements corresponding to UpperTriangularize

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

For a generally non-square matrix M, I want the upper triangle that include the diagonal entries. Specifically, this is implemented via `UpperTriangularize`:

```
MatrixForm[UpperTriangularize[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}]]
```

yields the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3\\0&5&6\\0&0&9 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Note, as per the documentation `UpperTriangularize` can also apply to non-diagonal matrices. Given the dimensions of the matrix, I want to return elements of the matrix that correspond to non-zero values of the resulting `UpperTriangularize` matrix.

This requires extending this [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3461/how-do-i-generate-the-upper-triangular-indices-from-a-list) to non-diagonal matrices and with the diagonal matrices. Any suggestions?

The desired output is a list of matrix elements that are non-zero. I.e. for a 3 by 3 matrix this should be the output:

{{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},...,{2,2},{2,3},...,{3,3}}

This should be generalised to the dimensions of the matrix. For this example, I'm currently using

```
Flatten[Append[{Subsets[Range[3], {2}]}, Table[{i, i}, {i, 1, 3}]], 1]
```

Wondering if there is a better approach.

Comment: What is the desired form of the output? Ragged matrix including empty lists, ragged matrix without empty lists, or a vector of the non-zero elements?

Comment: @BobHanlon, information added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** To get the position indices of the upper triangular part:

```
mat = Partition[Range[9], 3];
```

#### Tuples

```
Select[Apply @ LessEqual][Tuples[Range /@ Dimensions[#]]] & @ mat
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}
> ```

#### SparseArray

```
Sort@SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i <= j -> 1, Dimensions@#]["NonzeroPositions"] & @ mat
```

> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}

```
SparseArray[UpperTriangularize @ ConstantArray[1, Dimensions @ #]] 
    ["NonzeroPositions"]& @ mat
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}
> ```

#### Table

```
 Join @@ Table[{i, j}, {i, First@Dimensions[#]}, {j, i, Last@Dimensions[#]}] & @ mat
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}
> ```

#### Position

```
Position[UpperTriangularize[ConstantArray[1, Dimensions @ #]], 1, 
  Heads -> False] & @ mat
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}
> ```

#### MapIndexed

```
Join @@ MapIndexed[If[# == 0, Nothing, #2] &, 
   UpperTriangularize @ ConstantArray[1, Dimensions@#], {2}] & @ mat
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}
> ```

**Original answer:**

```
mat = Partition[Range[25], 5];

Row[MatrixForm /@ {mat, UpperTriangularize @ mat}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
MapIndexed[#[[#2[[1]] ;;]] &] @ mat
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {7, 8, 9, 10}, {13, 14, 15}, {19, 20}, {25}}
> ```

If you want to get a single list:

```
MapIndexed[## & @@ #[[#2[[1]] ;;]] &] @ mat
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 25}
> ```

Few additional alternatives:

```
MapIndexed[Drop[#, #2[[1]] - 1] &] @ mat
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {7, 8, 9, 10}, {13, 14, 15}, {19, 20}, {25}}
> ```

```
MapIndexed[Take[#, #2[[1]] - 1 - Length @ #] &] @ mat
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {7, 8, 9, 10}, {13, 14, 15}, {19, 20}, {25}}
> ```

```
Pick[#, UpperTriangularize@ ConstantArray[1, Dimensions@#], 1] & @ mat
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {7, 8, 9, 10}, {13, 14, 15}, {19, 20}, {25}}
> ```

If you need a single list, wrap the functions above with `Apply[Join]` or `Flatten`:

```
Join @@ MapIndexed[Drop[#, #2[[1]] - 1] &]@mat
```

> ```
>  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 25}
> ```

If the upper triangular part does not contain zeros (as in `mat`) you can also use  `SparseArray` and extract `"NonzeroValues"`:

```
SparseArray[UpperTriangularize @ #]["NonzeroValues"] & @ mat
```

> ```
>  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 25}
> ```

Comment: How to get the matrix elements corresponding to the non-zero entries? I.e. {{1,1}, {1,2}, .... {2,2},{2,3}, ... , {3,3}...}

Comment: @Sid, please see the update.

Comment: This is great. Is there a preferred route out of the `SparseArray`, `Table`, `Position`, and `MapIndexed` methods. My matrices are quite small so efficiency shouldn't be a bottleneck.

Comment: @Sid, if efficiency is not a concern; `Tuples` + `Select` is shorter than alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

(This answer was written before it became clear that the expected output is a list of positions. This answer is about how to retrieve the elements.)

Here's an implementation that support the second argument of `UpperTriangularize`:

```
upperTriangularElements[m_] := upperTriangularElements[m, 0]
upperTriangularElements[m_, k_] := Module[{nr, nc},
  {nr, nc} = Dimensions[m];
  Fold[
   #~Join~Diagonal[m, #2] &,
   {},
   Range[k, nc - 1]
   ]
  ]

m = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
m // MatrixForm
```

[image: Matrix]

```
upperTriangularElements[m]
```

> `{1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 3}`

```
upperTriangularElements[m, 1]
```

> `{2, 6, 3}`

This function also works for non-square matrices.

Answer (score 1):

```
(ArrayRules@UpperTriangularize[Partition[Range[9],3]])[[All,1]] // Most
```

> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}

```
(ArrayRules@UpperTriangularize[Partition[Range[12],4]])[[All,1]] // Most
```

> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}}